# Auth0 and AWS Policy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, policy, auth0

My web app is using Auth0 and AWS(Delegation token) to access to some resources in S3.

I have the following directory structure in a bucket named testinfo
-Directory1
    - Subdirectory11
    - Subdirectory11
-Directory2
    - Subdirectory21
-Directory3

I have the following Policy for S3 Buckets.
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1423804993000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::testinfo/Directory1",
        "arn:aws:s3:::testinfo/Directory1/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

And I have the following javascript code to show the contents of the bucket

```
var getTokenPromise = auth.getToken({api: 'aws', role: "xyz", principal: "xyz"});
getTokenPromise.then(function (value) {
    console.log('delegation: ' + value);
    bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'testinfo'}});
    bucket.config.credentials =new AWS.Credentials('x','y','z');
    bucket.listObjects({}, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            alert(err);
        var files = [];
        for (var i in data.Contents) {
            //show files
        }
    });
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('failed: ' + reason);
```

});

According to the policy, only the contents of Directory1 show be shown. Unfortunately I got an Access Denied Exception.
May someone give a hand to solve this problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding a wildcard to the directory, like this:

`"arn:aws:s3:::testinfo/Directory1/*"`

Comment: Hi Sandrino, thanks for your response. I added:
"arn:aws:s3:::testinfo/Directory1/*" , but I'm still having the same error